# API routes are not working in Laravel VueJS app

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, vue.js, vue-router

I'm building a SPA with Laravel and Vue. However, I need to make an API call with `axios` but it's not working.

Here's my `web.php`:

```
Route::get('/{any}', function () {
    return view('index');
})->where('any', '.*');
```

Here's my `api.php` route:

```
Route::get('/notification', 'NotificationController@index');
```

Whenever I make an API call, it shows a blank or broken page.

Could you please give me any suggestion about this issue and solve?

Comment: In web.php replace your `Route::get('/{any}'...` with Route::fallback https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#fallback-routes

Comment: @Guru But by doing this, I'm getting: UnexpectedValueException: Invalid route action: [App\Http\Controllers\/{any}].

Comment: You don't need `{any}` just `Route::fallback(function(){return ...})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should prevent api routes from being captured by web.php route.

First, prefix api routes:

`api.php`

```
Route::get('/api/notification', 'NotificationController@index');
```

Then, exclude prefixed routes from web routes:

`web.php`

```
Route::get('/{any}', function () {
    return view('index');
})->where('any', '^(?!api).*$');
```

Comment: Do I need to prefix it with /api in api.php or in web.php?

Comment: only api routes in `api.php`